# Once completing the thread the count down timer still working.. why is that?

Tags: timer, jmeter, countdown

I have used 100 users for my testing and it is completed 100 and it shows as 100/100 in the right-hand upper corner, but the timer is working? I don't know why is that..can you please explain to me why it happens like that. because when am using 5 users and once it completed timer is stopped. please help me. please check the attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any attachment however I can try to guess the possible reason.

When you start JMeter the following beautiful warning is displayed:

```
================================================================================
Don't use GUI mode for load testing !, only for Test creation and Test debugging.
For load testing, use CLI Mode (was NON GUI):
   jmeter -n -t [jmx file] -l [results file] -e -o [Path to web report folder]
& increase Java Heap to meet your test requirements:
   Modify current env variable HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" in the jmeter batch file
Check : https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
================================================================================
```

So my expectation is that 100 users is way too much than JMeter GUI can handle so consider [running your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) and it should end normally/gracefully. If it doesn't - make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)